# can not work well with send() and recv(),the 1st byte of a short string got lost.c++

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming

I am using send() and recv() in linux with c++.
I am trying to make up some kind of protocol.And some part of it works like:

1. A connect to B,B create a thread and wait
2. A send "backup" to B
3. B send "OK" to A
4. A send (some string like)"20001" to B.

In the last(4th) step A sends a short string to B,less than 10 bytes.
However when A sends a "20001" to B,B recvs a "0001",the **first byte** got lost,and I called recv() only once.
I checked the length,A send 6 bytes,B recv 18 or 19 bytes,the buffer that B used is 20 bytes long.Some of the codes:

```
send(datasock,conferenceid.c_str(),conferenceid.size()+1,0);//A send conferenceid,sent "20001" and returned 6 in the tests

char temp[20]={0};//B recv data
memset(temp,0,20);
recv(remote->sock_fd,temp,20,0);//got "0001" and returned 18 or 19 in the tests
```

The thing is,several hours ago in some other part of my pograme,when a "10001" was sent,a "001"   was recieved.Somehow it worked well now hours later.
I am not familiar with network programming.Someone can tell me where can I find the lost bytes?

Comment: You can't send 6 bytes and then receive 18/19 bytes. Those extra bytes don't exist. You MUST pay attention to the return values to know how many bytes were *actually* sent and received. And the *ONLY* way the first byte could be getting "lost" is if either 1) the sender never sent it in the first place, or 2) the receiver already received it in an earlier `recv()`.

Answer (score 1):

From `man send`

> RETURN VALUE
>
> On success, these calls return the number of characters sent. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

`send`, as well as `recv` (and also similar `write` and `read`) when used synchronously (meaning that application will be locked while waiting for packets) and when the size of packet is known should be wrapped in a loop like this (example for write):

```
int write_all(int fd, const char *buf, int n)
{
    int pos = 0;
    while (pos < n)
    {
        int cnt = write(fd, buf + pos, n - pos);
        if (cnt < 0)
        {
            perror("write_all");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (cnt > 0)
        {
            pos += cnt;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's what I want to tell you.B calls recv() function only once,and the first byte got lost.I mean if the last byte got lost I should understand what happened.It couldn't be recieved by another recv() function call.And I tried to call the recv() in a loop,it still got first byte lost.Anyway,it's a very short string,a loop isn't needed.

Comment: It is not possible for TCP to lose bytes, so either the sender never sent the byte in the first place, or the receiver is not reading it correctly. In any case, a loop is ALWAYS needed, because TCP is a byte stream, `send/write()` and `read/recv()` are NOT guaranteed to send/receive everything at one time, you MUST pay attention to the return values and repeat the send/recv as needed.